# Parallel of two shortcircuit

Tags: current, short-circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzCY3B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have trouble finding value for I2 current. Would I1 go through NODE1 down and close the loop, so I2=0, or go to the left from NODE1 so I2=-I1, or split (if we assume that both short circuit wires have no resistance) so I2=-I1/2. All explanations seems to me reasonable but I think only one is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question can't be answered from the model you have for the circuit.

If you take the short circuits to be ideal 0-ohm connections, then it doesn't matter which way the current goes. The voltage across the connecion is still 0 V, and the power used by the connection is still 0 W. And there is no way to tell which way the current flows.

If this is meant to represent a real circuit, then you need to include in the model the actual resistance of the "short circuits". Then you can use the current divider rule to determine the current through each path.

For example, maybe one is 1 milliohm and the other is 1 microohm. Then you'd know that about 999 mA flow through the lower-resistance path and 1 mA through the higher-resistance path.

Answer (score 0):

If this would be a **physical** circuit, for you to calculate the current distribution with reasonable accuracy you'd need:

- The gauge of the wire
- The specific resistance of the wire
- The length of both branches
- And technically speaking even the contact resistance for Node 1 and its opposite node

You wouldn't even be able to measure the current in a branch because the moment you insert an amperemeter the balance would be destroyed due to the internal resistance of the meter.

This is the reason care must be taken when wiring components that have a low internal resistance like coils and diodes in parallel .