# Analysis of a circuit with 6 diodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes, dc, voltage-source

Here is the circuit:
[image]

All of the diodes are ideal with Vf = 0. Determine Vx and Ix.

**My try:** We have 2^6 = 64 combinations of assumptions. My problem is D1 and D2. If we assume D1 and D2 are off then D3 should be on but there is no combination of other diodes such that leads to a valid answer. So we conclude that D1 and D2 both are on and this is meaningless. How two wires without resistance can be in parallel? Also how are we going to find the currents of D1 and D2 to check the validity of our assumption? I'm really baffled about this circuit.

Comment: Post more of your working. For example, you know that the top right of the circuit is at a potential of at least 1V. If D4 is off (which it definitely is), its relatively easy to say that the D5 is off, D6 is on, and the current through R3 is 1.1mA

Comment: Also D1 and D2 are not off, and D3 is on

Comment: @BeB00 My main problem is about D1 and D2. If we find the state of them, it's a easy task to find out others.

Comment: @BeB00 If D1 and D2 are on, how we can calculate currents of them?

Comment: If they are on, you know the voltage of the top left part of the circuit. You can then calculate the current through D3 (assuming D4 is off). Think about what this D3 current means, and how it's related to the D1 and D2 currents, and the R1 current.

Comment: Technically, you don't actually need any of these currents, since once you know that D1+D2+D3 are on, you know Vx and Ix. For the sake of completeness though, you should probably do it

Comment: One way to think of these diodes is as a series of voltage statements about the nodes they connect to. For example, D5 produces the statement "the top right rail is at a voltage >=0V". D6 produces the statement "the top right rail is at a voltage >=1V" and so on

Comment: @BeB00 We need to find currents for verifying of our assumption that D1 and D2 are on. The problem is that using KCL an KVL, we cannot determine currents of them. They are ideal diodes with Vf = 0. So there is no way for relating voltage and current in that branches.

Comment: " There is no way for relating voltage and current in that branches" how do you relate voltage and current in wires?

Comment: @BeB00 In other branches we have voltage source and/or resistor but when there are two parallel wires with zero resistance, it's impossible to find currents of them. See for example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150495/parallel-of-two-shortcircuit

Comment: Note that in that question, both answers said that it was impossible for a real/physical circuit. This is not a physical circuit, it's an ideal circuit, and in that case, the current is divided equally between parallel wires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So we conclude that D1 and D2 both are on and this is meaningless.

That's somewhat true. At the same time, it won't make any difference to the rest of the circuit if one of them is on and the other is off.

If they were real diodes instead of ideal ones, most likely one would be on and the other would be only nearly on.

> How two wires without resistance can be in parallel?

It's easy to put two wires in parallel.

The only thing that's difficult is to predict how much current flows through one and how much through the other.

> Also how are we going to find the currents of D1 and D2 to check the validity of our assumption?

You won't be able to tell how much current is flowing in D1 and how much in D2. You will be able to work out the total current shared by D1 and D2.

If your problem statement didn't ask you to determine how much current is flowing in each individual diode, you'll just have to accept this and move on.

If you problem statement asked you to determine the current in each diode, you'll have to make some reasonable assumption (like "they share the current equally" or "almost all the current flows through one and very little through the other"), state that assumption in your answer, and move on.

Comment: I think in an ideal circuit like this, mathematically the current flows equally in D1 and D2

Comment: @BeB00, you are welcome to make that assumption. But mathematically, the model is underdetermined, and any division of the current between the two diodes is a valid solution to the model presented (so long as neither current is negative). If there were wires in parallel instead of diodes, even solutions with negative current in one wire and positive current in the other would be valid solutions.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your answer. If we suppose that D1 and D2 are on then how can we check that is true or not? As you said calculating currents of them is impossible. We should see that whether i_D1 and i_D2 are positive or negative.

Comment: You can't really. One of them might be off (just on the inflection point between on and off). But it won't affect the rest of the circuit if only one of them is on.

Comment: I guess I would go the route of instead asking why they should be different. On the face of it, there are good reasons to assume that they are the same, and no good reasons to say that they are different. I agree now that it doesn't actually matter mathematically, but more from a perspective of understanding what we are trying to model. I would therefore say that we can reject solutions that work mathematically, but don't bear a relation to what we are trying to model, like we would in scenarios where a negative solution of a quadratic doesn't make sense

Comment: If they were real diodes, they'd be different because they'd be slightly different in construction and at slightly different temperatures.

Comment: @ThePhoton So you say that it's impossible to determine state of D1 and D2? I need a definite answer from the mathematical perspective.

Comment: Right, these are not real diodes, or resistors or sources, but we are trying to represent (perfect) real components. I think that, as an answer to the question, it would be valid to say that they pass the same current, and (very slightly) less valid to say that they have different currents. I also feel like this distinction might be unnecessarily confusing OP

Comment: @S.H.W, tough luck, you can't have it. Do you remember how you learned that a system of equations can have no solutions, exactly one solution, or infinite solutions? A circuit model is in a way a representation of a system of equations. And the system of equations in your model has infinite solutions. In one of those solutions D1 is on and D2 is off. In another, D2 is on and D1 is off. In the infinitely many other solutions, both are on.

Comment: @BeB00, I disagree about which assumption is more valid and which one is less valid.

Comment: Why? In exactly the same way we look at several (or infinite) mathematically correct solutions to other equations and choose some (or one) that are valid, and say the rest are invalid because they dont represent reality. This is a common problem when you abstract real situations to ideal mathematical equations, and selecting solutions based on information that you have about the system that isn't represented in the equations is an accepted practice

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh, I see. There are infinitely many solutions for that circuit. If only one of them is on then the voltage of the other diode is zero. In this case our assumption was true? I mean in general if the voltage of the ideal diode is zero it is off or on?

Comment: @BeB00, Because un-equal currents is much more likely to represent reality. Mathematically, with the model as given, there's no way to choose one solution or another.

Comment: @S.H.W, in a different circuit where both diodes were off, the voltage across them could be any negative value (i.e. cathode at a higher potential than anode)

Comment: @ThePhoton What about V_D = 0? If we assume that diode is off and then conclude  V_D = 0, was our assumption true or not?

Comment: That's an invalid inference for a diode in general. \$V_D=0\$ is what happens when the diode is on. \$I_D=0\$ is what happens when the diode is off. In this circuit, if one diode is off, \$V_D=0\$ because of the other diode in parallel, not because of the behavior of a diode when it's off.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry but I'm still confused. In general assuming that the diode is off (which means I_D = 0) and then conclude V_D = 0 is a contradiction, right?

Comment: Overall, the diode on/off state is decided by the current, not the voltage. I_D=0 and V_D=0 is not a contradiction. Imagine if you set all the voltage sources to 0V, all of the voltage differences would be 0, but would any of the diodes be on? 

I would argue that this is one (of the many) reasons to say that you should assume in an ideal world that both currents are the same, because in the real world, both diodes would be on (depending on your exact definition of on).

Comment: @BeB00 Okay, thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

Enough time has gone by. Your schematic is horribly drawn (perhaps by intention of its author.) Re-drawing it helps a great deal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJxWB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming ideal diodes with \$V_\text{FWD}=0\:\text{V}\$ and tentatively ignoring \$D_3\$ and \$D_4\$ for the moment, you can almost immediately see now that \$D_1\$ and \$D_2\$ are equally **on** and that \$V_y=0\:\text{V}\$ and also that \$D_6\$ will be **on** and pull \$V_z=1\:\text{V}\$ (\$D_5\$ will be **off**.)

Ignoring the resistors for a moment, you'd expect the *lower* of \$V_y\$ and \$V_z\$ to pull \$V_x\$ to its level. So ignoring the resistors, \$V_x=V_y=0\:\text{V}\$. Here, you also do NOT find any conflicts. In other words, this just means that \$D_4\$ is **off** and that \$D_3\$ is **on**. (And you'll note that \$R_1\$ can easily sink the current that \$R_2\$ can source.)

But suppose you take the other position; that \$V_x=V_z=1\:\text{V}\$? Then both \$D_3\$ and \$D_4\$ would be **on**, \$V_y=1\:\text{V}\$, and that \$D_1\$ and \$D_2\$ are **off**. But now this means that \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ can together sink far more current than \$R_2\$ can source, so this would pull \$V_x\$ well into the negative voltage region (but above \$-10\:\text{V}\$.) Both \$D_3\$ and \$D_4\$ would still be **on**, but \$V_x\$ and \$V_y\$ would also be well into the negative voltage region, too. But if so, \$D_1\$, \$D_2\$, \$D_5\$, and \$D_6\$ would all be **on** and would have \$V_\text{FWD}\gg 0\:\text{V}\$, which by definition cannot be the case.

So you don't need to go through all of the permutations to work it out.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. The main problem was about D1 and D2 because we can't find their currents when both are on. Only thing that we know for sure is the sum of currents.

Comment: @S.H.W You don't need to know their currents. Your question, as I read it, is asking for the current in \$R_2\$. That can be easily calculated.

Comment: That's right. At least one of the D1 and D2 are on. Anyway we have Vx = 0 and Ix = 0.1 mA.

Comment: @S.H.W Yes. That's the way I also see it. (You have 10 V divided by 100k Ohm.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @S.H.W At some point, and not necessarily now if you are still waiting for better answers, you should select an answer so that others don't waste their time trying to figure out and then write yet another way to answer this. It's respectful of the time of others, if you are satisfied. (Select any answer you are satisfied with. Just be aware that leaving the question open invites the time of others. If that's intended, fine. But if not, you should respect their time.) Also, if there's something missing in someone's answer, feel free to ask them to elaborate further.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming d1/d2 split  the current, the forward voltage will be 0.018 volts lower.

Comment: According to the problem statement, diodes are modeled with \$V_f=0\ V\$.